# Pass a taxonomy term slug to the code in functions.php

Tags: php, functions, custom-taxonomy, ajax

I need code which would load more posts into a div via WP ajax on a taxonomy term page. My code loads posts if I only specify custom post type without taxonomy term but I need it to load posts only of the taxonomy term on the taxonomy template page. My problem is that I can't pass a term slug to the code in functions.php file, it doesn't see it there `'terms' => $term_slug,`. I heard that it can be achieved by the WP_Term_query function but I couldn't figure out how to do that. I would be thankful for any working solution. Thanks! My code is this below.

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_tax_results', 'load_tax_results' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_tax_results', 'load_tax_results' );

function load_tax_results() {
 
  $termid = get_queried_object()->term_id;
  $myterm = get_term($termid, 'product-type');
  $term_slug = $myterm->slug;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'site-product',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product-type',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $term_slug,
      ),
      ),
    );
    

    $wquery = new WP_Query($args);

if( $wquery->have_posts() ) :
   
while($wquery->have_posts() ) : $wquery->the_post(); 
?>

 // stuff


<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif; 

 
wp_die();
            
}
```

custom.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

let loadMoreButton;

loadMoreButton = $('#comp-load-more-btn');
  
  let currentPage;
  currentPage = 1;

  loadMoreButton.on('click', function(e) {

    currentPage++;
    
      e.preventDefault();

      var button = $(this);

      $.ajax({
          url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
              'action': 'load_tax_results',
              'paged': currentPage,
          },
          beforeSend: function() {
              button.text('Loading...');
          },
          success: function(response) {
              // Append the new posts to the container
              $('#posts-here').append(response);
 
              button.text('Load more...');

              // Hide the button if there are no more pages
              if ('' === response) {
                  button.hide();
              }
          } 
      });
  });

});
```